# In GWT, how well supported are the 2.0 layouts (i.e. LayoutPanel subclasses) in different browsers?

Tags: gwt

So I'm getting started with GWT and learning how to use the new LayoutPanel stuff, but in the documentation, the 2.0 layouts are guaranteed to work in standards-mode only. Moreover, in the GWT Designer, the help text for some panels (i.e. DockLayoutPanel) says, "this widget will *only* work in standards mode".

So I'm a bit nervous about how well they currently work across different versions of different browsers. I have created examples to test, but of course the nasty bugs will only show up once the layout becomes more complex. So have any of you run into issues or caveats with the GWT 2.0 layouts? Or are they pretty stable across a broad range of browsers? I recognize that I might have to exclude anything <= IE6.

EDIT: To clarify, I know that I'll need to set the DOCTYPE to standards-mode. I just don't know how well it will *work*.

Comment: I am VERY interested in using UiBinder, but I think that's immaterial to my question. Unless I'm mistaken, the end-result code and resultant html/javascript isn't any different. If there's a browser-related bug with DockLayoutPanel, for example, it will show up whether I define it in UiBinder or explicitly in the Java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use `LayoutPanel` extensively in our application and find that it works consistently across all of our supported browsers (Currently: IE 7, 8 & 9; Firefox 4, 5 & 6; Chrome stable & dev; Safari 4 & 5). We have seen zero nasty bugs or inconsistencies from our use of `LayoutPanel`s.

Comment: That's good, if a bit terse. Do you mostly extend LayoutPanel, or do you use the existing subclasses? Do you tend to use widgets or html in your layout structure? Do you use any nested layouts?

Comment: We primarily use bare `LayoutPanel`s with `Widget`s in UiBinder templates. We do a lot of nesting and use `LayoutPanel`s for both top-level layout and individual controls.

Comment: Ditto for us.  We use LayoutPanels the same way, with many nested layoutpanels, and also more LayoutPanels inside floating dialog boxes.  They seem very stable and widely supported (3 months, hundreds of weekly visitors, zero layout complaints)